# Why dropEvent is not getting called?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I implement drag&drop feature to my project. I can drag&drop.It works fine but override method not getting called.

Am I missing something ?

```
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)override;
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)override;
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)override;
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)override;
```

```
void InformationMusteriDialog::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) {
    QMessageBox::information(this,"dropEvent","dropEvent");
}

void InformationMusteriDialog::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"mousePressEvent","mousePressEvent");
}

void InformationMusteriDialog::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"mouseMoveEvent","mouseMoveEvent");
}

void InformationMusteriDialog::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"dragEnterEvent","dragEnterEvent");
}

void InformationMusteriDialog::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"dragMoveEvent","dragMoveEvent");
}
```

when i drag or drop nothing pops up.
(I'm reading these links contents for 2 days. Please dont say read the doc again)
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html
https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405546

I read this but mine still not working
[dropEvent() not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159915/dropevent-not-getting-called)

Comment: The description is confusing. You say that drag and drop works but the override methods are not called. So how can it work? Also it is not clear what works and what not. Does `mousePress` event work? And `mouseMove` event? Btw. have a look at this https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#acceptDrops-prop (this should be set for the widget) and also https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdropevent.html#acceptProposedAction which should be probably called in `dragEnter` event and `dragMove` event. These are just hint, I have not implemented d&d for a long time so I do not remember the details...

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager I can drag items and drop one listview to another one. But I wanna do something when drop happened so I override the dropEvent method. Fill the inside of the method. However nothing happens.

Comment: You need to create minimum reproducible exmaple. From the code above, it is not possible to find out what is wrong. Btw. have you tried the methods which I suggested above? Also you might need to set `QWidget::setMouseTracking(true)` for your dialog. But I am not 100 % sure about it.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager yes i tried. It still drops but does not called the dropEvent function. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371120/how-to-do-action-when-qstringlistmodel-changed> look at this link i put a image about what I'm trying to say. The listview model is changing when I change items order and i can print however the method does not called still.