# How to do action when QStringListModel changed?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qstringlist, qstringlistmodel

Basically, I have 2 listviews and when I drag&drop one listview to another one,I want to execute a sql query.

I tried to override dropEvent but it does not getting called. However the drop action happening.(I go through the model data with for loop and I can print the items in the model)

[image]

Why the dropEvent not called when drop happens ?

```
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)override;
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)override;
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)override;
    void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *event)override;
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)override;
```

```
void InformationMusteriDialog::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) {
    QMessageBox::information(this,"x","xss");
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem if anyone curious about this problem.

I thought I can connect QStringListModel with SIGNAL and SLOT.

```
connect(ui->listViewMusteri->model(),&QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged,this, &InformationMusteriDialog::listViewMusteriChanged);      
connect(ui->listViewToplam->model(),&QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged,this, &InformationMusteriDialog::listViewToplamChanged);
```

When model's data is changed, you can do something.

(btw I'm keep searching about DnD methods.)